# PostgreSQL Find and Replace in JSONB Data as text

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, syntax-error

I have some JSONB data that looks like this:

```
content
id       fields
0        {image: 'https://olddomain.com/file.jpg'}
1        {image: 'https://oldodmain.com/file2.jpg'}
```

I want to do a find and replace on it as if it were a text field.  I tried this:

```
UPDATE content SET fields::text = REPLACE(fields::text, 'https://olddomain.com', 'https://newdomain.com');
```

But that is getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 12):

The result of a cast isn't an l-value, and you cannot assign a value to it. You could, however, take the text result of the `replace` call and cast it back to `jsonb`:

```
UPDATE content 
SET    fields = 
       REPLACE(fields::text, 'https://olddomain.com', 'https://newdomain.com')::jsonb;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93ec1/1/0)**